# library(venn), change font size

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I have a very simple question regarding the library venn.
I need to increase the font size represented in each set and intersections.
How to do that?
The guide points to the parameter "par", and checking in "par" it seems that cex is the parameter that control the font size.  But in even if I change it, the image in the output remains the same.  What's the problem here?

```
library(venn)

alist=list()
alist[[1]]=sample(1:20,  10)
alist[[2]]=sample(1:20,  10)
alist[[3]]=sample(1:20,  10)


png("atest.png")
venn(alist, par=(cex=6))
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: With the parameters `icls` and `sncs` you can increase your fontsize. e.g. `venn(alist, ilcs = 3, sncs = 3)`

Comment: Totally right, and I totally missed that in the help.  It's fixed, thank you.